# Assertion Error loading graphene schema with Django choices

Tags: django, graphene-python

I'm pretty new to Django/Graphene, using it very basically in a new project.

I have this class with choices:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    """
    A question that was asked. who asked, when and what answers did it get
    """
    QUESTION_TYPES = (
        ('YN', 'Yes No'),
        ('MC', 'Multiple Choice'),
        ('OP', 'Open ended')
    )
    _question_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=QUESTION_TYPES, default='OP')
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    by_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

It seems that when the server is loading my Graphene's schema (I execute runserver and point my browser to the url), I get an assertion error in: 
`graphene/types/typemap.py in graphene_reducer, line 73`

Using a debugger - I can tell the assertion break when the "type-maps" compares the enum generated by my Django model (Question) and the one Graphene is using (wrapped/converted). attached a snapshot of of the debugger's breakpoint:

[image]

I fail to understand why the expression `_type.graphene_type == type` evaluates to `False`

I'm using Phyton 3.5, Django 1.10.5, Graphene 1.2.1

Comment: possibly related to https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/87  (?)